# Angular 8 Weird Routing Issue After Deployed to Github Pages

Tags: angular8, angular-routing, github-pages

This App works fine locally, and everything seems fine after I depolyed it onto Github pages, form working, API working, buttons working... BUT, everytime when I refresh the page, I got a 404 page(Except home page somehow), then if I click the logo on nav bar, it supposed to redirect back to home page, instead I got 404 page as well.

[Image of home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aiGo.png)

---

I had problem with base-href when building the App, I tried diferent solutions foundon web, set base-href to the following: angularTest, "/angularTest", "/angularTest/" or as Angular doc suggests "https://xxx.github.io/angularTest" something like that, all of them got blank page when deployed to github pages, 404 error in console, and this is the only way it would work:

```
ng build --prod --base-href=""
```

Project name is angularTest by the way.

Anyone knows how to fix this? Much appreciated!

*Link to deployed App: https://nay-said.github.io/angularTest/*

---

*app.component.html:*

```
   <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-md">
    <a href="/" class="navbar-brand ml-5">
        <h3>Angular Demo</h3>
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" 
             aria-controls="navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a routerLink="form" routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-link text-white"><h6>Form</h6></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a routerLink="/listings" routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-link text-white"><h6>Listings</h6></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a routerLink="/calendar" routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-link text-white"><h6>Calendar</h6></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

*routes:*

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent},
  { path: 'angularTest', component: HomeComponent},
  { path: 'form', component: ContactUsComponent},
  { path: 'listings', component: ListingsComponent},
  { path: 'calendar', component: CalenderComponent},
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
export const routingComponents = [
  HomeComponent, 
  ContactUsComponent, 
  ListingsComponent,
  CalenderComponent
]
```

Comment: I am having the exact same issue! Where you able to solve it?

Comment: Also because of this issue the assets on the page will not load either!

Answer (score 2):

As is stated in the Angular documentation on deploying apps on github pages [here](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#deploy-to-github-pages)

`When the build is complete, make a copy of docs/index.html and name it docs/404.html.`

This did the trick for me!